# SpotFire: Sum over region average over time while toggling the date axis (from month to year)

Tags: spotfire, tibco

Consider following data with following columns Region, Demand (is in ton per day basis) and Date.

[image]

Now when i open a Bar Chart with Date on x-axis (Year>>Quarter>>Month>>Day) and Sum(Demand) on Y-axis.

This is correct only on Day level, when i toggle to month, quarter and year, i want it to sum over region for a particular date then average over month/quarter/year where ever the toggle is set.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same challenge and just found a solution today :)

You need to insert "Hierarchy" for the date on x-axis and use the "Hierarchy" as x-axis.

My example:

[image: Inter Hierarchy]

[image: Count by Year/Quarter/Month]